# Drive unable to boot

Tags: boot

OS Ubuntu 22.04 Desktop

Drive: 1TB PCIe3.0 NVMe SSD

This drive has been running for long time.  Until last week it is unable to boot dropping to GRUB shell.

Just ran `boot-rescue` on an USB Ubuntu 22.04 installer but still failed.
On reboot it till drops to GRUB shell.

I have copied the `Boot-Info_20230412_0503_copy.txt` file here which was download before running `boot-rescue` option;

```
boot-repair-4ppa2056                                             
[20230412_0503]

============================= Boot Repair Summary ==============================

User choice:

Is there RAID on this computer? no


==================== blkid (filtered) before lvm activation ====================

/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root:
UUID="ef229efa-3019-4ba9-bddc-88c399244e99" BLOCK_SIZE="4096"
TYPE="ext4" /dev/nvme0n1p1: UUID="0E3A-4ABA" BLOCK_SIZE="512"
TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="925d583f-d383-49d0-9a23-7efb9ffdc926" /dev/sda1:
BLOCK_SIZE="2048" UUID="2022-08-10-16-21-45-00" LABEL="Ubuntu 22.04.1
LTS amd64" TYPE="iso9660" PARTLABEL="ISO9660"
PARTUUID="9240a165-d190-4ab6-8a11-46dc207b42ee"
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1:
UUID="ae829a93-d744-47b2-b378-85d58950c720" TYPE="swap"
/dev/nvme0n1p2: UUID="WmiqMV-mxBN-xNbz-WKk3-04Qm-OEvb-gfo2C6"
TYPE="LVM2_member" PARTUUID="531826ba-1f9a-4196-91ce-99c81f8b8be0"
/dev/sda4: LABEL="writable"
UUID="24e801fa-b8fe-4c56-bf40-9c7f3b2f987c" BLOCK_SIZE="4096"
TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="d8f8ab1c-ad26-2248-b668-c6f7539df4b8" /dev/sda2:
SEC_TYPE="msdos" LABEL_FATBOOT="ESP" LABEL="ESP" UUID="8D6C-A9F8"
BLOCK_SIZE="512" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="Appended2"
PARTUUID="9240a165-d190-4ab6-8a12-46dc207b42ee" /dev/sda3:
PARTLABEL="Gap1" PARTUUID="9240a165-d190-4ab6-8a13-46dc207b42ee"


================================ LVM activation ================================

modprobe dm-mod   vgscan --mknodes   Found volume group "ubuntu-vg"
using metadata type lvm2 vgchange -ay   2 logical volume(s) in volume
group "ubuntu-vg" now active lvscan   ACTIVE           
'/dev/ubuntu-vg/root' [<930.37 GiB] inherit   ACTIVE           
'/dev/ubuntu-vg/swap_1' [976.00 MiB] inherit blkid -g



Default settings:
______________________________________________________________

The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility would not act on the
boot.

User settings:
_________________________________________________________________

[dmraid -sa -c] no [dmraid -sa -c] raid [dmraid -sa -c] disks [dmraid
-sa -c] no [dmraid -sa -c] raid [dmraid -sa -c] disks No OS to fix. No OS to fix. Please backup your data before this operation. The settings
chosen by the user will not act on the MBR. Additional repair will be
performed:  repair-filesystems


Force Unmount all blkid partitions (for fsck) except / /boot /cdrom
/dev /etc /home /opt /pas /proc /rofs /sys /tmp /usr /var

fsck -fyM /dev/nvme0n1p1 fsck from util-linux 2.37.2

Boot successfully repaired.

You can now reboot your computer.


============================ Boot Info After Repair ============================

 => No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/nvme0n1.

nvme0n1p1:
_____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  FAT32
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /efi/BOOT/fbx64.efi /efi/BOOT/mmx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/mmx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/shimx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg

nvme0n1p2:
_____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       LVM2_member
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

sda:
___________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       iso9660
    Boot sector type:  Grub2 (v1.99-2.00)
    Boot sector info:  Grub2 (v1.99-2.00) is installed in the boot sector of 
                       sda and looks at sector 0 of the same hard drive for 
                       core.img, but core.img can not be found at this 
                       location.
    Mounting failed:   mount: /mnt/BootInfo/FD/sda: /dev/sda already mounted or mount point busy.


================================ 1 OS detected =================================

OS#1:   Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS on mapper/ubuntu--vg-root

================================ Host/Hardware =================================

CPU architecture: 64-bit Video: Picasso/Raven 2 [Radeon Vega Series /
Radeon Vega Mobile Series] from Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
Live-session OS is Ubuntu 64-bit (Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS, jammy, x86_64)

===================================== UEFI =====================================

BIOS/UEFI firmware: 1201(5.14) from American Megatrends Inc. The
firmware is EFI-compatible, and is set in EFI-mode for this
live-session. SecureBoot disabled (confirmed by mokutil). BootCurrent:
0003 Timeout: 1 seconds BootOrder: 0002,0003 Boot0002*
ubuntu  HD(1,GPT,925d583f-d383-49d0-9a23-7efb9ffdc926,0x800,0x100000)/File(\EFI\UBUNTU\SHIMX64.EFI)..BO
Boot0003* UEFI:  USB, Partition
2   PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1,0x2)/Pci(0x0,0x0)/Pci(0x8,0x0)/Pci(0x0,0x3)/USB(7,0)/HD(2,GPT,9240a165-d190-4ab6-8a12-46dc207b42ee,0x71e8a0,0x2130)..BO

a9c517741ac31962d7feb152948ad1ee   nvme0n1p1/BOOT/fbx64.efi
a660182adef313615746a665966d2ccc   nvme0n1p1/BOOT/mmx64.efi
3f347c1ffd7bf309741eb7cfbdff2ab6   nvme0n1p1/ubuntu/grubx64.efi
a660182adef313615746a665966d2ccc   nvme0n1p1/ubuntu/mmx64.efi
64349b3622c65f495a99dbf6102496e3   nvme0n1p1/ubuntu/shimx64.efi
64349b3622c65f495a99dbf6102496e3   nvme0n1p1/BOOT/BOOTX64.efi

============================= Drive/Partition Info =============================

Disks info:
____________________________________________________________________

nvme0n1 : is-GPT,   no-BIOSboot,    has---ESP,  not-usb,    not-mmc,
no-os,  no-wind,    2048 sectors * 512 bytes

Partitions info (1/3):
_________________________________________________________

nvme0n1p1   : no-os,    64,
nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   not-far

Partitions info (2/3):
_________________________________________________________

nvme0n1p1   :
is---ESP,   part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot

Partitions info (3/3):
_________________________________________________________

nvme0n1p1   :
not--sepboot,   no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, nvme0n1

fdisk -l (filtered):
___________________________________________________________

Disk nvme0n1: 953.87 GiB, 1024209543168 bytes, 2000409264 sectors Disk
identifier: 271E9246-CC54-4368-8693-FDCC3EE8AB23
            Start        End    Sectors   Size Type nvme0n1p1    2048    1050623    1048576   512M EFI System nvme0n1p2 1050624 2000408575
1999357952 953.4G Linux LVM Disk mapper/ubuntu--vg-root: 930.37 GiB,
998974160896 bytes, 1951121408 sectors Disk mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1:
976 MiB, 1023410176 bytes, 1998848 sectors Disk sda: 57.3 GiB,
61530439680 bytes, 120176640 sectors Disk identifier:
9240A165-D190-4AB6-8A10-46DC207B42EE
        Start       End   Sectors  Size Type sda1       64   7465119   7465056  3.6G Microsoft basic data sda2  7465120   7473615      8496 
4.1M EFI System sda3  7473616   7474215       600  300K Microsoft basic data sda4  7475200 120176576 112701377 53.7G Linux filesystem

parted -lm (filtered):
_________________________________________________________

sda:61.5GB:scsi:512:512:gpt: USB  SanDisk 3.2Gen1:;
1:32.8kB:3822MB:3822MB::ISO9660:hidden, msftdata;
2:3822MB:3826MB:4350kB::Appended2:boot, esp;
3:3826MB:3827MB:307kB::Gap1:hidden, msftdata;
4:3827MB:61.5GB:57.7GB:ext4::;
mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1:1023MB:dm:512:512:loop:Linux device-mapper
(linear):; 1:0.00B:1023MB:1023MB:linux-swap(v1)::;
mapper/ubuntu--vg-root:999GB:dm:512:512:loop:Linux device-mapper
(linear):; 1:0.00B:999GB:999GB:ext4::;
nvme0n1:1024GB:nvme:512:512:gpt:INTEL SSDPEKNW010T8:;
1:1049kB:538MB:537MB:fat32::boot, esp; 2:538MB:1024GB:1024GB:::lvm;

blkid (filtered):
______________________________________________________________

NAME                  FSTYPE      UUID                                
PARTUUID                             LABEL                   
PARTLABEL sda                   iso9660     2022-08-10-16-21-45-00    
Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS amd64  ├─sda1                iso9660    
2022-08-10-16-21-45-00                
9240a165-d190-4ab6-8a11-46dc207b42ee Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS amd64 ISO9660
├─sda2                vfat        8D6C-A9F8                           
9240a165-d190-4ab6-8a12-46dc207b42ee ESP                     
Appended2 ├─sda3                                                      
9240a165-d190-4ab6-8a13-46dc207b42ee                          Gap1
└─sda4                ext4        24e801fa-b8fe-4c56-bf40-9c7f3b2f987c
d8f8ab1c-ad26-2248-b668-c6f7539df4b8 writable                  nvme0n1
├─nvme0n1p1           vfat        0E3A-4ABA                           
925d583f-d383-49d0-9a23-7efb9ffdc926                          
└─nvme0n1p2           LVM2_member
WmiqMV-mxBN-xNbz-WKk3-04Qm-OEvb-gfo2C6
531826ba-1f9a-4196-91ce-99c81f8b8be0                            
├─ubuntu--vg-root   ext4        ef229efa-3019-4ba9-bddc-88c399244e99  
└─ubuntu--vg-swap_1 swap        ae829a93-d744-47b2-b378-85d58950c720  


Mount points (filtered):
_______________________________________________________

                                                               Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/disk/by-label/writable[/install-logs-2023-04-12.1/crash]  49.9G  
0% /var/crash
/dev/disk/by-label/writable[/install-logs-2023-04-12.1/log]    49.9G  
0% /var/log /dev/nvme0n1p1                                            
504.9M   1% /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p1 /dev/sda1                                                          0 100% /cdrom

Mount options (filtered):
______________________________________________________


============================== ls -R /dev/mapper/ ==============================

/dev/mapper: control ubuntu--vg-root ubuntu--vg-swap_1

=================== nvme0n1p1/efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg (filtered) ===================

search.fs_uuid 124bd5c8-06be-4244-a082-8d34ae704c79 root
lvmid/nT9xpi-M23I-Mt8N-tcoP-6rAx-4woi-1DbrQw/rajeHn-w4Y5-oadp-CCOp-bbl4-qMzA-aIKYie
set prefix=($root)'/boot/grub' configfile $prefix/grub.cfg
```

Please help.  Thanks in advance.

Regards

## Edit

On booting, no error info popup just drop to GRUB screen.

This SSD is still working. When I boot another drive on this PC, I can still connect this SSD via File Manager, retrieving its files.

Comment: You have tons and tons off info here but no clear error. Does it produce an error? If it has been running for a long time, actual time unknown maybe the drive has failed. Your question says it fails. What fails? As written there is noting to help with.